Flutter - IntelliJ IDEA can't find JAVA_HOME after executing flutter run after upgrading Macos Sequoia
I'm using M3 Pro Sequaoia. I got a flutter project, running flutter run I got this error
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Running flutter doctor -v I got

Running:
zhelon@MacBook-Pro-M3-de-Sebastian-2 ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME

(nothing)

Running:
zhelon@MacBook-Pro-M3-de-Sebastian-2 ~ % which java
/usr/bin/java

Running:
zhelon@MacBook-Pro-M3-de-Sebastian-2 ~ % java -version
openjdk version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.12+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.12+0, mixed mode, sharing)

I just reinstalled intellij IDEA and Android Studio.
This is my android sdk:

.bash_profile
# export PATH=”/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH:/Users/zhelon/development/flutter/bin”
export PATH=”$PATH:/Users/zhelon/development/flutter/bin”

# export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

can I get some hand please?

I had the same issue, but it was not for macos Sequoia, I just reunistall everything and works. Good luck with that

Apart of reinstalling, you can try installing jdk21 using brew with brew install openjdk@21
then replace your .bash_profile and .zshenv with
export PATH=”$PATH:/Users/zhelon/development/flutter/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin”
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@21"
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

then refresh source ~.bash_profile and source ~.zshenv
finally try
flutter config --jdk-dir $JAVA_HOME
and should work

That works, but I'm using jdk17. I'm going to change that in your solution. Thanks
